# Custom SQL for inital migration for custom field

Tags: python, django

Can I define somehow custom SQL, that I want to be written in initial migration for a model that uses my custom field? Like `CREATE TYPE` in PostgreSQL.

### UPDATE #0

I'm talking about reusable application that implements field.

Comment: Update #0: So this will not be an initial migration during `migrate` execution? How can an initial migration be reusable?

Comment: @Wtower I'm talking about SQL code generation.

Comment: Ok, could you please edit your post and provide all relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the initial migration and add your custom sql using [migrations.RunSQL()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)